# how can I find the variance of the reciprocal of the mean for a random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, variance

I am trying to find the variance of $\frac{1}{x  bar}$ given a Poisson random variable.

Now I have no idea as to how I can manipulate the expectation in regard to this finite sum, I am guessing i have to find $E(\frac{n}{\sum{xi^n}})^2-(E\frac{n}{\sum{xi^n}})^2$

Now I can take out $n$ squared from both expectations and factor it out, but I am struggling to conceptualize the expectation of the reciprocal.

Comment: Note that the reciprocal of the mean is not the mean of the reciprocal.

Comment: Asymptotic variance can be calculated using [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables). If $X_i$'s are independent Poisson, then $\sum X_i$ is also Poisson.

Comment: But $\bar{x}=0$ with non-zero probability, so surely the variance of $1/\bar{x}$ is undefined?